# Adobe Reader shows embedded qualified timestamp could not be verified

Tags: cryptography, certificate, adobe, pdfbox, digital-signature

I signed PDF document with Qualified Electronic Signature and Qualified Timestamp. For some reason Adobe Reader thinks the timestamp could not be verified. All other validators show the signature being valid PAdES-BASELINE-LT. What could the cause of it?

Exact error message "The signature includes an embedded timestamp but it could not be verified"

[image]

Comment: Please share an example PDF for analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Adobe Reader does not make use of the EU LOTL and EU MS TLs “directly” but rather use an Adobe-specific format (similar to the AATL) to configure trust anchors derived from the EU MS TLs.

So in general the content of the Adobe-specific EU TL can differ (desynchronization) from the latest published EU MS TLs.

Most probably, the timestamp has been generated by a "recently" qualified time-stamping service, which has not (yet ?) been included in the Adobe-specific EU TL.

Comment: New qualified timestamp certificate was recently created. Adobe had some issues of publishing new EU Trust Lists. Now Adobe has confirmed that the lists have been published and issue was resolved.